# Segmentation fault and warnings in kurento media server

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, kurento

I have issue with kurento media service. Sometimes it's broken with next warnings and error(unfortunately kurento logs without timestamps):

1st issue :
I have a lot of next warnings:

> (kurento-media-server:17737): WARNING **: Error sending data on stream 1: (104) Connection reset by peer

2nd issue:

> ** (kurento-media-server:7829): WARNING **: SCTP event
>   SCTP_COMM_LOST received

I tnink it's network issues but I don't know something...

3th issue:

> (kurento-media-server:7829): libnice-WARNING **:
>   (agent.c:2156):agent_signal_component_state_change: runtime check
>   failed: (TRANSITION (DISCONNECTED, FAILED) || TRANSITION (GATHERING,
>   FAILED) || TRANSITION (CONNECTING, FAILED) || TRANSITION (CONNECTED,
>   FAILED) || TRANSITION (READY, FAILED) || TRANSITION (DISCONNECTED,
>   GATHERING) || TRANSITION (GATHERING, CONNECTING) || TRANSITION
>   (CONNECTING, CONNECTED) || TRANSITION (CONNECTED, READY) || TRANSITION
>   (READY, CONNECTED) || TRANSITION (FAILED, CONNECTING) || TRANSITION
>   (DISCONNECTED, CONNECTING)|| TRANSITION (CONNECTING, GATHERING))

Some guys from StackOverflow said, it's not a problem

4th issue:

> [31;1mSegmentation fault[0m (thread [33;1m139796485371648[0m, pid [33;1m7829[0m)
>       Stack trace:
>       [34;1m[g_socket_send_message][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0[32;1m:0x7B044[0m
>       [34;1m[nice_output_stream_new][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnice.so.10[32;1m:0x2769E[0m
>       [34;1m[nice_output_stream_new][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnice.so.10[32;1m:0x27813[0m
>       [34;1m[nice_agent_recv_nonblocking][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnice.so.10[32;1m:0x11879[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_nice_src_get_type][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstnice15.so[32;1m:0x3902[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_nice_sink_get_type][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstnice15.so[32;1m:0x4203[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_base_sink_do_preroll][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x2A1B2[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_base_sink_do_preroll][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x2B620[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_flow_get_name][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x6E5CF[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_pad_push][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x76533[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_proxy_pad_chain_default][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x5F5E3[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_flow_get_name][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x6E5CF[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_pad_push][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x76533[0m
>       [32;1m0x1B48D[0m at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstcoreelements.so
>       [34;1m[gst_flow_get_name][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x6E5CF[0m
>       [34;1m[gst_pad_push][0m
>       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x76533[0m

I have kurento 6.7 , ubuntu 16.04 in DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your 1st issue means:-**
There is some network fluctuation ,try application in 4G network you will not receive a warning. You can ignore these warning ,but you should handle the onIceCandidate responses.

**Your 2nd Issue:-**
Again your 2nd issue is related to network , but this time its in KMS end.
KMS not able to transfer some data packets thats why this warning comes.

**Your 3rd Issue:-**
it's not a problem.Its just a warning when websocket flailed to get runtime issue status.